# Does the concept of liberation differ among six orthodox Hindu philosophical schools?

Tags: vedanta, sankhya, shad-darshana, nyaya, vaisheshika

The six schools of Hindu philosophy have many differences. As far as I know, a soul is an atom according to the Nyaya-Vaisheshika school. According to Samkhya, there are many souls, and they are pure consciousness. On the other hand, Advaita claims there is only one consciousness, and the rest is a delusion.

So, I guess the definition of Moksha or state of liberation might be different according to different schools. I am looking for authoritative verses from the Sutras and Karikas of respective schools describing the state of Moksha.

By the way, I am not talking about the different ways of attaining moksha according to different schools. It already has an answer here ([What is the means of attaining Moksha according to the different Astika schools?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21656/what-is-the-means-of-attaining-moksha-according-to-the-different-astika-schools)). I wanted to know what different schools mean by Moksha? Interested to know Whether the definition varies. So my question is not a duplicate of that question.